# how do I return values from an array to populate href values

Tags: javascript, jquery

var standard = $(function(){

```
                        //should return reversed iterated standard anchor array
                            $.each(standard_anchor,function(value){ return (value) })  

                            });
```

/////

$(function(){

```
    /*  should  replace all a href values with reversed iterated standard anchor data   */
         $('a [href]').reverse().each().attr('href', function(){ return ( standard) });


});
```

/////

so that's what I tried but it didn't work, and I don't know why it didn't work, any suggestions?

standard_anchor is the array name, and var standard is a function I thought could return those array values when used in a function.

Comment: I formatted your code example. Next time, please format your code properly yourself, as it might help to get more attention to your problem by others.

Comment: FYI: `document.links` can be used in place of your query.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$('a [href]').reverse().each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('href', standard_anchor[i]);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much however it didn't work here's a copy of the whole js maybe you'll see what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

var standard was not defined properly, it was enclosed in a jquery method, try this.

```
var standard = function(){

   //should return reversed iterated standard anchor array
   $.each(standard_anchor,function(value){ return value });  

};

(function(){

   /*  should  replace all a href values with reversed iterated standard anchor data   */
   $('a[href]').reverse().each().attr('href', function(){ return standard(); });


});
```